# GPS is Not Working Galaxy S5?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Am using Location Services in Android to access the users current Location through Google Location Client API . In Mobile, GPS in Enable only but in coding it show GPS is Disabled in `Samsung Galaxy S5`. Am in India am check with many mobile all working fine here. That `Samsung Galaxy S5` mobile in Australia. Is there any restriction to access the GPS in Country Wise. `Google map , Uber App` are all working fine. Am gave the **Debug.apk** to that Australian guy to check. Can any one know help me solve the issue.

Here is my Code:-

**To check GPS is enable or Not:-**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
   toast("GPS Not Eabled")
}
```

**To Get the User Location**

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();

locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    location_get();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void location_get() {

    mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {

        current_latitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        current_longitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get location using  GPS then it will take some time to fixed at least 3 GPS .

Comment: @Yugesh check if google play services are not there may be issue that google may not be avaliable for galaxy s5 refer here http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

Answer (score 1):

GetLastLocation only works if you've already gotten the location and cached it.  You need to request location updates to start the location subsystem.  Note that this may take several second to minutes if using GPS, or may even never occur if you can't get a signal.

Comment: okay. But `if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
   toast("GPS Not Eabled")
}` always it enters into this `if condition` if GPS enabled.

Comment: That means that GPS is enabled, not that its on.  It means you can use, not that it has a signal lock.  It would return false if the user had turned off GPS in settings, for example.

Comment: All things are Enabled in **Location Service Settings**.

Comment: Like I said-  that doesn't mean its on.  GPS isn't on unless an app is actively requesting it, because it burns battery.  a requestXXX function turns it on.  GetLastLocation doesn't, so it won't have a location to return unless some other app turned it on recently.

Comment: I Got Your Point GetLastLocation is okay. For Example - Am click the Button to get the users Location. At the time of user click the button first am check the **GPS** is enabled or Not(My problem is here itself). Then only am going to get the Users Current Location.